How does Kant define an agent capable of judgment?
Specifically, since we cannot know any object is not a reasoner (as the external world isn't reliable), we couldn't know if anything is a reasoner, so would have to treat everything as a reasoner, meaning we cannot confer value onto any object, thereby making any ethical action impossible?
It seems like the two main answers to this are:

The verifiability of someone else's agency isn't contingent on universalizability tests (i.e. I know lying is bad, just assume everyone is an agent — you still get a contradiction in conception)
Sure, we can't verify. Worst case scenario we just be really nice to rocks, dogs, blades of grass etc.

But I think 1 doesn't hold up because it isn't a question of universalizability. And 2 is wrong because it still means we couldn't do something like build a house. Cutting down a tree to make the wood planks to build a house would be using the tree as a means to an end.
Does Kant expect us to "err on the side of caution" in estimating who/what is to count as an agent-with-reason, or does he think that there are clear/objective standards for judging which objects of perception count as agents, standards which seems to rule out a great many objects from moral consideration (e.g. flecks of dust, clouds, distant galaxies)?
I need help thinking of an answer to this. Thanks.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I'm confused by the phrase "any object can be a reasoner."  What exactly does that mean and where are you getting that from? I don't recall reading any such thing from Kant.  Does that mean that any object can have qualia associated with consciousness?

Judgement is defined by Kant as that which forms sensibly intuitive hypotyposis instead of the rationally symbolic analogical one thus intuition and Kantian categories are involved here, even considering his reflective, moral and non-discursive aesthetic judgment...

This is a tricky issue because of Kant's position that his empirical realism and transcendental idealism are two sides of the same doctrine (A edition of the CPR). Let me examine your question closely:

Specifically, since we cannot know any object is not a reasoner (as the external world isn't reliable) . . .

Kant rejects this with his empirical realism (phenomena are indeed perceived objectively what they are: phenomena), and his "proof" that outside world exists (B edition of the CPR). Kant would likely say you are asserting the outside world is unreliable because you are still clinging to the view that perception should be of things as they are in themselves, and not what they are for us.
Why is this tricky? Because it was clear to those at Kant's era that we have no direct perceptual evidence of other minds: we only perceive their bodies. Kant even enshrines this when he asserts that our inner consciousness of ourselves is conditioned by the a priori form of time and not space. So one could conclude that direct access to the mental life of others is precluded because we condition all external perception with space as the form of intuition of the external world—a form not applicable to "inner sense."
I'm unaware of Kant providing a solution to the "problem of other minds," and he lived in a time where it was taken for granted that Europeans had reason. Given the above, I see a simple answer: if a being can invoke inner sense in a rational manner, then they must have reason. Well, what is the synthetic a priori knowledge tied to inner sense alone for Kant? Arithmetic.
If one can intuitively tell that 7+5=12, then they have both an inner sense and have reason. A calculator is no good because they operate by rote or brute force in giving answers. So asking someone (or something) why 5+7=12 (which they proceed to count on their fingers, utilizing inner sense rationally) would tell you if you are merely talking to a machine vs. a rational being.
Does this exclude infants? Definitely, but the Kantian standard for possessing humanity is the power of reason. It comes with the territory and deserves its own examination as a separate question.

+1 As for excluding infants, one might suspect that the commonsensical view that the potential to have rationality would be enough to diffuse the trivial objection.
